# Error while opening Software Center and Update Manager in Xubuntu

Tags: software-center, xubuntu, update-manager

Using Xubuntu 12.

I can't open either the Software Center or Update Manager. I'm a complete novice!

I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute command "/usr/bin/software-center %u".
Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/software-center" (No such file or directory)
```

I tried all I can think of by update via Synaptic package Manager  but nothing I've done works.

I've the CD  but now I'm used to this and I don't want to do a clean install and lose all my files etc.

Can a repair be done? or can it be repaired with the CD?

I'm not that good with computers but absolutely love Xubuntu?

Please make my day and tell me it can be solved!

**Edit**: Some outputs which may help.

```
alan@alan-Aspire-2930:~$ cd /usr/share/software-center/; ls | grep ^software-center$ 
software-center
```

it means there is `software-center` and is not deleted.

```
alan@alan-Aspire-2930:/usr/share/software-center$ sudo ln -s '/usr/share/software-center/software-center' '/usr/bin'
[sudo] password for alan: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/software-center': File exists 
alan@alan-Aspire-2930:/usr/share/software-center$
```

it means symbolic link also exists. It is very strange because when you run `software-center` it says `(No such file or directory)` !!!

Answer (score 1):

`cd /usr/share/software-center/`

`ls | grep ^software-center$` does this yield any output? if yes then only the symbolic link is deleted from `/usr/bin/`.

to create symbolic link again,

```
sudo ln -s '/usr/share/software-center/software-center' '/usr/bin'
```

if this doesn't help

try reinstalling `sofware-center`. It seems like python script of software center has been deleted or moved.

**edit >**

try `sudo apt-get install software-center`